# CSS transitions for SVG fill not occurring simultaneously

Tags: css, transition

I have an SVG embedded in my HTML that I am trying to animate it's transition to a different spot on the page. During it's transition, I need it to resize width and height, change location (left and top), and inverse it's fill colors.

The embedded SVG looks something like this:

```
<svg class="svg-transition" style="fill: rgb(0,0,0)" title="SVG1">
    <path d="..."></path>
    <path d="..."></path>
    <path class="svg-transition-color-2" d="..." style="fill: rgb(255,255,255)"></path>
</svg>
```

I have this working flawlessly for single-color SVGs. They move, resize, and recolor simultaneously so that the new color is complete by the time the item is finished moving/resizing.

To accomplish this, I run this code:

```
$(".svg-transition[title='SVG1']").css(
    { 'left': x, 
      'top': y, 
      'width': w, 
      'height': h, 
      'fill': '#fff', 
      'transition': 'left 1s, top 1s, width 1s, height 1s, fill 1s ease-out' 
    }
);
```

The problem comes when the SVG has multiple colors in it that need changed during transition. In this example, any path with a class of `svg-transition-color-2` is a different color than the rest of the SVG. I can get the SVG to behave like it should, except for paths with `svg-transition-color-2`. These paths stay the same color throughout the transition, then once the transition is complete, their transition starts. I need these paths to transition at the same time that the main transition is taking place.

I currently run the above jQuery line, then run this afterwards:

```
$(".svg-transition[title='SVG1'] .svg-transition-color-2").css(
    { 'fill': '#000', 'transition': 'fill 1s ease-out' }
);
```

I've messed around with the transition, tried removing it completely (thinking that transition will inherit from the SVG), etc...

I tried to make a jsfiddle of the problem, but I cant get jsfiddle to transition left, top, width, or height, and I can't get it to behave the same way as my code does. FWIW i also cant get jsfiddle to behave the way I want it to, either.